# How do i coding aframe assets in threejs way

Tags: three.js, aframe

This is some aframe code `<a-camera position="0 0 0" look-controls="enabled: false"></a-camera>` ，now i want to work with threejs code,so which is the right way about coding ,I don't know if this is right
`let camera = document.createElement('a-camera'); camera.setAttribute('look-controls', 'enabled: false'); camera.setAttribute('position', '0 0 0');`

Comment: You should probably take the “Getting started” tutorial: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene

Comment: I think It would be better if you'd use threejs code in [custom components](https://aframe.io/docs/1.4.0/introduction/developing-with-threejs.html) rather than try and manage `aframe` and `threejs` in a js file.